# Google Sheets App Script | While loop until two consecutive empty cells in first column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for help to code this while loop condition so that it specifies to loop until two sequential cells in the first column are empty.

**Currently triggering code as a macro, for testing.*

---

```
function doubleEntry() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var firstEmptyRow = sheet.setActiveSelection(sheet.getRange("A"+getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow()));

//Condition that specifies to loop until the cell 1 below the first column of the firstEmptyRow is empty
  
while() {
  
    //selectFirstEmptyRow
    firstEmptyRow.activate();

    //conditionalFill
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
      
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IFS(R[0]C[1]="Owner Withdrawal","Dividends",R[0]C[1]="Supplies","Expenses",R[0]C[1]="Services","Expenses",R[0]C[1]="Cash", "Assets", R[0]C[1]="Equipment", "Assets", R[0]C[1]="Accounts Payable", "Liabilities", R[0]C[1]="Owner Equity", "Equity", R[0]C[1]="Retained Earnings", "Equity", R[0]C[1]="Revenue","Revenue", R[0]C[1]="Accounts Receivable", "Revenue")');
    
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[-1]C[0]="Owner Withdrawal","Cash")');
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[0]C[1]="Cash","Assets")');
      
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 2).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[1]');
      sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
      sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[-1]');

  }
};
```

[Link to example sheet, shown below in screenshot](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JL2v7IPS9Ka8017IfmMsTdUJmvenfD_WCtJRU2l0KXA/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

````
    function insertAllRowsThenAppend() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
  var sheetData = sourceRange.getValues();
 // var firstEmptyRow = sheet.setActiveSelection(sheet.getRange("A"+getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow()));
  
  
//InsertRows() {

  for (var i=1; i < sheetData.length; i++) {
  // var i=1 inserts row after, i=0 inserts row before.
    if(sheetData[i][0]!=""){
         sheet.insertRowsAfter(i+1, 1);
         sheetData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    }
  }

  for (var i=1; i < sheetData.length; i++) { // var i=1 inserts row after, i=0 inserts row before.
    if(sheetData[i][0]!=""){
      //sheet.insertRowsAfter(i+1, 1);  
      sheetData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

          //selectFirstEmptyRow
         // firstEmptyRow.activate();

          sheet.setActiveSelection(sheet.getRange("A"+getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow()));

          //conditionalFill
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');


          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IFS(R[0]C[1]="Owner Withdrawal","Dividends",R[0]C[1]="Supplies","Expenses",R[0]C[1]="Services","Expenses",R[0]C[1]="Cash", "Assets", R[0]C[1]="Equipment", "Assets", R[0]C[1]="Accounts Payable", "Liabilities", R[0]C[1]="Owner Equity", "Equity", R[0]C[1]="Retained Earnings", "Equity", R[0]C[1]="Revenue","Revenue", R[0]C[1]="Accounts Receivable", "Revenue")');
        

          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[-1]C[0]="Owner Withdrawal","Cash")');
          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[0]C[1]="Cash","Assets")');
          
          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 2).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]');
          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[1]');
          sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
          sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[-1]');
 
    }
  }
};```
````